# How do I send a negative value in python's socket.setsockopt?

Tags: python, sockets

```
import time
import socket

# creating a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                  socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVLOWAT, -1)
```

Returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 7, in <module>
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVLOWAT, -1)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

If i try to make the same call in C++ i'm allowed to send negative integers as a value through setsockopt. When I check the return value in C++ it returns 0, so I know that -1 should be a valid value in the linux kernel's sock_setsockopt. Not sure why it's not the case with Python3.

Comment: What would you expect the behaviour of `SO_RCVLOWAT = -1` to be?!

Comment: Actually it's to test a new sockopt value i added in the linux source code... -1 is supposed to disable the feature. @deceze .

Comment: Surely the line of code causing the problem is given in the traceback?